# Java Scanner Read from File

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, java.util.scanner, readfile

Let me first establish the following fact: I am new to java, so please be patient.

In my programming class, we were given an exercise to do at home using the Scanner class. The activity shows the following coding to exercise with:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileReadWrite {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
          String[] strArr = new String[100];

          int size = 0;

          try {
               Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("Names1.txt"));
               while (scFile.hasNext()) {
                    strArr[size] = scFile.next();
                    size++;
               }
               scFile.close();

               for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    System.out.print(strArr[i] + " ");
               }
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
          }

     }
}
```

The program seems to not be working correct. I use NetBeans to run the code, and when I run the code, it does not display the data in the text file, Names.txt. Why is that? The program does however Build completely without errors.

I have tried going through the Scanner class javadocs, but it's not helping me.

Please explain to me so that I can learn from the mistake made.

Thanks,
Johan

Comment: Is there an error or ... ?

Comment: Please elaborate on "seems to be not working".

Comment: @kbbucks How will new String() help?

Comment: Try using a debugger (you can do this through NetBeans). Add a breakpoint before your loops, and check the condition of the program at that time. You'll be able to figure where its failing.

Comment: Your code seems correct; maybe you could use an ArrayList or allocate more memory to that array if your file contains more than 100 characters? Or at least tell us how is not working correct :)

Comment: There's no error. The code simply does not show the items in the text file. It doesn't give me a FileNotFound Exception, so it definitely finds the file. It just doesn't run the program to show the data in the text file. The output is just blank, and then it says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a working example. Perhaps try using a BufferedReader.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanXan {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner s = null;

    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(s.next());
        }
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my mac, and it works. So I thought you might input a wrong path of Names1.txt file.

In Java, when you simply use "what_ever_file_name.txt" as the path of file, Java will only search the file in your source code folder. If nothing found, a "FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION" will be thrown.

Comment: It definitely finds the file, because it doesn't throw a "FileNotFound Exception". I have put the file in the src folder so that it can find the info easy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user2170674. I also tried your code in a Windows machine, using Eclipse, and everything went well. Maybe you are putting your file in the wrong path. Two options:

- you could use the full path, like (if you're using Windows) "C:\Names1.txt";
- or, a more generic solution, using JFileChooser:

  ```
        // create your FileChooser
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        // open the FileChooser
        int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        // if you select a file
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            // get the file and do what you need
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        } else {
            // throw an exception or just a message in the log...
        }
  ```

Comment: I'll give the JFileChooser a try. Not sure iff I'm allowed to use it in the exam, though. I have changed the path, and still it doesn't give me what's inside of the file. Is the data in the text file maybe wrong? How should it look like? I created my own file in my stupidity, because they didn't give us one.

Comment: Hi Joan,

There are some alternatives to investigate the problem:

* Did you try to debbug your code, to see what's happening, line by line?
* What's being printed in the console?

About the data in the file being wrong: I gave you the suggestion to use JFileChooser just to guarantee that your are getting the correct file. And how should the content of the file look like? Just text, with the return character at the end of each line, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good.
Debug with a few messages.
At end, add a `System.out.println()` or `System.out.flush()`.
Move exception block location to just after file use (minimise try block size) and move close() within finally block.
Make sure you view Netbeans output window (Window -> Output -> Output)

```
public class FileReadWrite {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      System.out.println("##### Starting main method...");
      String[] strArr = new String[100];

      int size = 0;

      try {
           Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("Names1.txt"));
           while (scFile.hasNext()) {
                strArr[size] = scFile.next();
                size++;
           }
           System.out.println("##### Finished scan.  Found %d tokens.", size);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
      } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
           if (scFile != null) {
               scFile.close();
               System.out.println("##### Closed scanner.");
           }
      }
      System.out.println("##### Printing tokens...");

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           System.out.print(strArr[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("##### Exiting main.");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the trouble in coding all this! It seems though that there's an error in the coding. When I try to run that, I get three initial errors in NetBeans. 1) Line15: System.out.println.....  ERR: No suitable method found for println(String, int). 2) Line22: scFile != 0..... ERR: Cannot find symbol. 3)Line23: scFile.close()..... ERR: Cannot find symbol

Comment: So after minor adjustments to the coding, I got it running, but it still gives me the above mentioned problem where it's not showing what's inside the txt file. It goes through everything, prints ever line in the code, but when it has to print the tokens, it makes a new blank line, then continues to Exiting main.

Comment: Try this to print tokens: System.out.print("<"+strArr[i] + ">,");  Does it print lots of empty tokens?: <>, <>, <>,

Comment: Nope, still just one empty line

Comment: Try working with the following: L1`Scanner scFile = null;` L2 `scFile=new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Names.txt")));`  I got it to show the names all in one line, but as follows: `Name1 <Name1>, Name2 <Name2, etc...`. I don't want it like that. I want only the first part, <> omitted, and each name should be on its own line.

Comment: Still an empty line?  Just above this did it print "##### Finished scan.  Found 0 tokens"?

Comment: Yes, it printed that. I have managed to tweak the code. An error you made was omitting f in printf ("Finished scan. Found %d tokens", size); The coding is running smoothly now. I had made a mistake in the previous tweak. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK.  So it found nothing then.  So scFile.hasNext() returned false, right from the start.  Check:  File file = new File("Names1.txt");  if (!file.exists()) System.out.println("File doesn't exist!!!!!!!);  Then temporarily test with ";" as delimiter; before while: scFile.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(";")).  Put ";" into file instead of whitespace.